# Entity Framework Cascading Delete 0..1 to 0..1 code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following three poco classes in my model

```
public class Item 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DbImage Image { get; set; }
    //other properties
}

public class Creature
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DbImage Image { get; set; }
    //other properties
}

public class DbImage 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    private byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to configure fluent API in a way that removing an Item or Creature will automatically remove the corresponding image? Every image belongs either to an item or a creature.

I have tried the following fluent API configuration:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasOptional<DbImage>(i => i.Image).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
```

this lead to the following migration:

```
AddForeignKey("dbo.Items", "Image_Id", "dbo.DbImages", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
```

the consequence is now that deleting an image leads to removal of the corresponding item or creature, not the other way around. I have tried many other things, but i cannot fight the right way to make this happen. Can someone tell me whether or not this is even possible at all?

Comment: DbImage should have the foreign key to Item and Creature. That's two FKs. Is that what you intend? Otherwise you have to look into polymorphic associations.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you should define the relationship as required on the DbImage site:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasOptional<DbImage>(i => i.Image).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Thanks to this no additional Image_Id property will be added to Item but instead rleationship will be based on primary keys in Item and DbImage.